# I'm iLvl 641 resto druid and average 20K healing what am I doing wrong

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I have studied the rotations for the druid on the 6.0.3 and am pretty sure I am following them (although I may be forgetting something).

Here are the average stats (per tick and by seconds):

- Wild Mushroom : 2.5K/pop (1.5K/sec)
- Healing Touch : 18K
- Regrowth : 10K
- Lifebloom : 1.5K/pop (2K/sec)
- Rejuvenation (with germination) : 2.5K/pop (2K/sec)
- Swiftmend : 17K

[Armory Link](http://us.battle.net/wow/en/character/zuljin/Nifer/simple)

I must admit, I did not boost my character (gems/enchants) as of now, and do not exactly intend so before I can stabilise a bit my equipment (after I'll finish gearing up I guess).

I guess I am looking at some tips to make sure if I forgot something (equipment/rotation/something else) that might help boost my healings. So far, most of the healers get around 25K/30K on  raids, I have a hard time following them.

Comment: Are the other healers of the same class?  Different classes will rank differently on the various fights.  Also, what's your latency/average fps?

Comment: I see other druids going around 30K/sec for heals.

Comment: How are you positioning Wild Mushrooms? Because those things can really add to the healing.

Comment: Targetting the tank most of the time. Otherwise I position it on myself when I'm in a crowd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WoW is *very* gear based, especially from a PvE standpoint. Considering that your rotation is pretty much the same as the other healers, and that you are attentive to your assignment (tank, dps, raid heal, etc) - the main difference will be your gear.

So much of a character is their weapon. I could not help but notice yours is only blue at the moment. I know that finding new weapons can be difficult, but this is the largest source of the gap between you and other healers.

I would actively attempt to replace your weapon with a higher level one. After that you can focus on replacing the hands, waist, and legs.

In addition, in the mean time you should use at least lower level cheap gems in open sockets. It is a free bonus, and every little advantage helps.

It seems that you are on your way to being at the higher hps rates, you just need to have a little bit of patience, and perhaps some luck with drops :)

Comment: So it's "mostly" a question of weapon ? I'll try to change that and see how it goes.